# UILabel not displaying words after line break

Tags: ios, uilabel

I'm displaying a UILabel inside a UITabelViewCell - and I am trying to get the overflowing text to the next line. This worked fine, when I used the "Title" ProtoType Cell - but since I switched to a Custom Cell with one UILabel (So i can adjust the width of UILabel) things seem a bit broken.

#### Answer (Provided by Jack Wu): Label too small to hold 2 rows.

This is what I'm doing, and how I am trying to set the Line Break:

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:200];

[label setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[label setNumberOfLines:0];
```

This is how my IB looks like: 
[image]
What happens: 
The Text is being cutoff at the width of the label - but no linebreak is happening.
This is how it looks (see the Cells with the trailing `,`, those are cut off)
[image]

What am I missing here?

Edit: Using `[label sizeToFit]` results in following:

[image]

Comment: Check if the label != nill. If not, check: label.frame?, label is visable? Try to set a background color if the text is attached.

Comment: Label is not nil, all the other things are set. The Text is being displayed, a new line is just not being inserted correctly

Comment: Make the Y origin of the label smaller or make the cells bigger when using `-sizeToFit`. Otherwise, you are setting the width of the label too high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit2:** It looks like your label is too small for the text. You could try resizing the height of the label to accommodate multiple lines of text

**Old Answer** ---

**Edit:** Looking at your response to the other solution, it looks like the label is line breaking properly but the text is too big for the label.

There could be a few issues

1. Is there a "..." appearing in your label? If so, the line break mode is not set properly.
2. It may simply be that your label is too small to hold the text. You need to allow the label to shrink the text automatically or increase the size of the label

   ```
   //iOS 7 
   label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5 // Scales the text down
   //iOS 6 and prior
   label.minimumFontSize =  8 // Or whatever font point
   ```

Comment: Adding this, has sadly no effect on the outcome :( - Also updated the post with the IB - The label should not be too small.

Comment: In the interface builder my option is the "Autoshrink" option right below line breaks. From the pictures you posted it looks like your label is being resized? Its smaller in the posted screenshot compared to the IB size

Comment: Also note that in your IB it looks like your label can only hold 1 line of text, unless you are dynamically sizing your table cells or the label. Without autoshrinking the text will not wrap if the label is too small.

Comment: AH! Resizing the height of the Label worked! Thank you! (Can you please edit your answer?)

Answer (score 0):

try to use this line

```
[label sizeToFit];
```